# Flexslider 1.8 in Wordpress - Adding thumb navigation / editing options

Tags: wordpress, flexslider

I'm working on a Wordpress theme that uses Flexslider 1.8

http://wp.themecss.com/Square/portfolio-item/graphicriver/

I wish to add the thumbnail-slider controlNav feature that I've seen on the flexslider and github sites.

I've found some code examples of whats needed to do this, however I'm not sure on how/where to implement these changes.  Is it in jquery.flexslider.js? Is there any other files within the theme that also required changing e.g .css?

I'm fine hacking away at php, but this is the first time I've tried to edit .js in a theme

So, I could really do with some help with

1. What is the code required to implement this?
2. What files required editing to achieve this?